# PhPMailer - how to force gmail to show the name argument from the SetForm?

Tags: php, email, gmail, phpmailer

I use PhpMailer and Google apps (with a simple contact form). Let's assume my main email (set up with Google apps) is info@company.com. The PhPMailer code is standard, like below:

```
<?php
include "classes/class.phpmailer.php"; // include the class name
$mail = new PHPMailer(); // create a new object
$mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
$mail->SMTPDebug = 1; // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // authentication enabled
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for GMail
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->Port = 587; // or 587
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Username = "info@company.com"; //MX records set up to use Gmail servers
$mail->Password = "xxxxxxxxx";
$mail->addReplyTo($_POST['email]);
$mail->SetFrom("info@company.com","Company Name");
$mail->AddAddress("help@company.com");
$mail->Subject = $_POST['subject];
$mail->Body = $_POST['body];
$mail->Send());
?>
```

---

My problem is - in Gmail I always see such submitted emails sent from 'me' (ie. from info@company.com). But it is not convenient because I want to see some other unique info about the sender. Obviously, changing this part above to:

```
$mail->SetFrom($_POST['email]);
```

would be considered email forgery and cannot be used any more with Gmail STMP. **HOWEVER**, why this doesn't work (ie. doesn't change the name associated with email):

```
$mail->SetFrom('info@company.com', $_POST['email]);
```

? After all, isn't the second argument in the SetForm the receipient's name? Why gmail doesn't list this name and it continues to list 'me' as the sender?

I even tried this:

```
$mail->SetFrom('info@company.com', 'Customer Request');
```

and in Gmail it is still listed as 'me' - why isn't it listed as 'Customer Request'? Name shouldn't be considered as 'forged'?

Is there a way to force to show name from the SetFrom instead of 'me' in Gmail?

*I attach a screenshot of where the 'me' appears (it appears on the main gmail tab).*[image: 'Me' always appears]

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if it's saying 'me' because it's your account that you received it in and gmail is overriding it - have you looked at it in a different account?

Comment: BTW I can see that you're using an old version of PHPMailer. [Get the latest from GitHub](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer).

Comment: That's the issue (I tested it on the newest PHPMailer too, no difference)..

Comment: In that case you may as well close the question i.e. it's nothing to do with PHPMailer.